# How do I remove all keys except one with jq?

Tags: json, key, filtering, jq

Given a list of objects, with many keys I don't want:

```
[{
    "name": "Alice",
    "group": "Admins",
    "created": "2014"
}, {
    "name": "Bob",
    "group": "Users",
    "created": "2014"
}]
```

How do I filter these objects to only include keys I want?

```
[{
    "name": "Alice"
}, {
    "name": "Bob"
}]
```

I've tried `jq '.[].name'` but that extracts the values, rather than preserving the objects.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `map()` function to filter any key:

```
jq 'map({name: .name})'
```

#### Update

Suggested by [`@WilfredHughes`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509706/wilfred-hughes): The above filter can be abbreviated as follows:

```
jq 'map({name})'
```

Comment: Ah, works perfectly! You can even shorten it to `jq 'map({name})'`

Comment: Or `jq '{name}'` if the input is a dict.

Answer (score 23):

you can use `map` with `del` if you know the keys you don't want:

```
jq 'map(del (.group) | del (.created))'
```

Comment: answer fine but if there are many keys then `del` not good idea

Comment: shorter: `map(del(["group","created"]))`, although this is only suitable for blacklist

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer (with `map`) and the equivalent answer by @mauricio-tranjano will, in effect, add the specified key to objects that don't already have it.  If that's not the behavior you want, then consider using `has(_)`, e.g.:

```
$ jq -c 'map( if has("a") then {a} else {} end )'
```

Input:

```
[{id:1,a:1}, {id:2}]
```

Output:

```
[{"a":1},{}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution without the `map` function:

```
jq '[.[] | {name: .name}]'
```

Comment: besides the outer square brackets are kind of unnecessary (it just makes the whole output an array like the input is), as in @x-yuri's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838154/how-do-i-remove-all-keys-except-one-with-jq#comment100346322_27838881) shown, the filter can be shortened to only `{name}`. if you want to keep more than one key/value combination, you can make it a list in the curly braces like `jq '.[] | {name, group}'` (in this case i'm just keeping the filter before the pipe, to demonstrate that normal object filter can be used beforehand).

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `map()`? `echo '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]'| jq '[.[] | {a: .a}]'` vs `echo '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]'| jq 'map({a})'`. You convert an array into a stream (a sequence of JSON values), then back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

This would allow keeping a set of fields (matched by regex).

```
map(
  to_entries
  |map(select(.key|test("^(name)$")))
  |from_entries
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**8 years later...**

As of [`jq` version 1.7](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7), [`pick`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#pick) can be used:

```bash
jq 'pick(.[].name)'
```