# How do I simplify a JSON object using JQ?

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

I've got a huge JSON object and I want to filter it down, to a small % of the available fields. I've searched some similar questions, such as [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838154/how-do-i-remove-all-keys-except-one-with-jq) but that is for an array of objects. I have a JSON object that looks something like:

```
{
"timestamp":1455408955250999808,
"client":  
    {
    "ip":"76.72.172.208",
    "srcPort":0,
    "country":"us",
    "deviceType":"desktop"},
"clientRequest":
    {
    "bytes":410,
    "bodyBytes":0}
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new JSON object that looks likes:

```
{
"timestamp":1455408955250999808,
"client":  
    {
    "ip":"76.72.172.208",
     }
"clientRequest":
    {
    "bytes":410
    }
}
```

So effectively filter down the data. I've tried:
`| jq 'map({client.ip: .client.ip, timestamp: .timestamp})'` and I continue to get:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "client"
```

Even the most simple `| jq 'map({timestamp: .timestamp})'` is showing the same error.

I thought I could access the K,V pairs and use the map function as the person did for his array in the question linked above. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Huzzah. Simple enough really :)

```
cat LogSample.txt | jq  '. | {Id: .Id, client: {ip: .client.ip}}'
```

Basically define the object yourself :)

Comment: It's even simpler than that: there's no need for the initial `.`, and "Id: .Id" can be abbreviated to "Id" here.  So: `jq '{Id, client: {ip: .client.ip}}' would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will be simplest if you construct the object you want.  Based on your example, you could do so using the following filter:

```
{ timestamp,
  client: { ip: .client.ip },
  clientRequest: {bytes: .clientRequest.bytes }
}
```

By contrast, `map` expects its input to be an array, whereas your input is a JSON object.

Please also note that jq provides direct ways to remove keys as well, e.g. using `del/1`.

Comment: Thanks @peak, as a follow up question, how can I create the object if, and only if, the entry exists in the json i'm observing. i.e. the incoming json has no value for .client.ip and i'd rather not create that field if it does not exist. this method would force the creation with and empty .client.ip field.